# Websphere 7 and EJB 2.1 - JNDI name not specified

Tags: ejb, websphere, ejb-jar.xml

Environment - WAS 7.0 and EJB 2.1

I have a EAR with EJB jar file. It has some remote EJB's (EJB 2.1) that I want to convert to local EJB. Hence i had to modify ejb-jar.xml as per my understanding.

My modified ejb-jar xml file is as follows:

```
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
....
...
<session id="Manager">
            <ejb-name>Manager</ejb-name>
            <home>com.aa.bb.ManagerHome</home>
            <remote>com.aa.bb.ManagerRemote</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.aa.bb.Manager</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <local-home>com.aa.bb.ManagerLocalHome</local-home>
            <local>com.aa.bb.ManagerLocal</local>
            <ejb-local-ref id="EJBLocalRef_1139997836094">
                <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ManagerLocalHome</ejb-ref-name>
                <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
                <local-home>com.aa.bb.ManagerLocalHome</local-home>
                <local>com.aa.bb.ManagerLocal</local>
                <ejb-link>Manager</ejb-link>
            </ejb-local-ref>
```

,  and  are newly added tags for the local ejb.

And my Bindings file is as follows -

```
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi" xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmi:id="EJBJarBinding_1107442316219">
                <ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
                .....
                .....
            <ejbBindings xmi:id="EnterpriseBeanBinding_1142021363669" jndiName="ejb/ManagerLocalHome">
                <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:Session" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Manager"/>
                <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1315855161720" jndiName="OraDataSource">
                    <bindingResourceRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ResourceRef_1142023723001"/>
                </resRefBindings>
            </ejbBindings>
```

During deploy of the EAR file I get the following error -

*com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: 
             ADMA0014E: Validation failed. ADMA0007E: A Validation error occurred in task Mapping EJB references to enterprise beans.

             The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for reference binding ejb/ManagerLocalHome in module ZZZZZ with EJB name Manager.*

Any idea why it would complain about JNDI when it has been defined ?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the jndiName should jndiName="ejb/Manager" in the bindings file and it started working for me.
Had to run it rhought rmic but the lookup is now working.